# Qt program using Matlab dll, Initialized successfully in local disk, but failed in My U disk

Tags: c++, matlab, qt

I am writing a Qt program using matlab dll, the matlab function is very simple, However I encountered some exception caused by initializing problem. So I have changed my part of code as below.

```
void DicomViewer::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    if(libMyAddInitialize()){
        mwArray dicomArray2=Mat2mwArray(dicomMat1);
        //c_matlab(1,dicomArray2,Mat2mwArray(dicomMat1));
        mwArry2Mat(dicomArray2).copyTo(dicomMat2);
        dicomImgShow(TEMPDICOM2);
        libMyAddTerminate();
    }
}
```

This part of the code provides a button to change my cv::Mat data. I am using two functions `Mat2mwArray`and`mwArray2Mat` to convert Mat between mwArray. Funciton `dicomImgShow` is to show the Mat to My program. That I think code is not the key problem.

**My Key problem is The button function only work in my local disk (C:/ and D:/).** I put it into my U disk and it failed. I also tried to run it in admin mode, but failed again. So I wonder what's wrong in my program.

Thanks for anyone who come to help .

Comment: Concerning network drives, permission issues would be my first thought. However, another possible issue could be which DLL is really used. If in doubt try [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/). Sometimes, you will be surprised which DLL is used (and how it is found due to `%PATH%` settings).

Comment: "it failed" is not a very useful diagnostic. Please copy-paste any error messages you got, and/or describe the behavior in more detail.